# Representing a point's x-coordinate in a Bokeh Plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have a set of points in (X,Y) format. I created a plot (using the Bokeh package) which represents all the Y values and the number of time it has occurred in the set.

Given an X value, I want to represent the corresponding Y value on the plot.

I am looking for a plot similar to the image.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSDCu.png)

Comment: What does "representing" mean? Are you asking for an interactive hover tool? Or a permanent annotation?

Comment: Not exactly a hover tool. I want a pop up to be displayed when I give the X value.

Comment: What does "give the X value" mean? When you enter it interactively in some input widget? A permanent label set programmatically? You need to explain precisely, in much more detail, what it is you are trying to make happen.

Comment: @bigreddot Not necessarily some input widget. What I am trying to do is to initially make a plot and after that, for each of the X,Y pair I am trying to generate a plot which highlights just that Y value on the plot and displays a tab with the X and Y values.

Comment: The question is still not completely clear. As best I can tell, you want to be able to annotate a specific point programmatically. I've added an answer that demonstrates that. If that's not correct, then you need to edit your question to be more narrow and include actual code, specifically a complete script showing what you have tried that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to label specific points, one way is to use the `Label` annotation:

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import Label

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)

p = figure()
p.line(x, y)

# define the distinguished point
x0, y0 = x[175], y[175]

# label the distinguished point
p.circle(x=x0, y=y0)
citation = Label(x=x0, y=y0,
                 text='x: %f y: %f' % (x0, y0),
                 x_offset=5, y_offset=5,
                 border_line_color='black',
                 background_fill_color='lightgray')
p.add_layout(citation)

show(p)
```

Which results in:

[image]

Note that `Label` does not yet support line breaks. I you need that, you can either:

- split things into two labels that you add separately
- use `p.text` which doe support newlines (but only renders text, background or border)